# Social security Regular Expression validator in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

i want to use regular expression to validate SSN with dashes.  This is the format i would like to see: 000-00-0000. This expression does not work for me for some reason.

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}|\\d{9})$" ControlToValidate="txtSSN" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how i resolved:

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to note about the [`RegularExpressionValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx):

> It will never be activated by an empty string in the control it is
>   validating. Only the RequiredFieldValidator catches empty strings You
>   do not need to specify beginning of string and end of string matching
>   characters (^ and $)—they are assumed. If you add them, it won't hurt
>   (or change) anything—it's simply unnecessary.

You could just refer to an example regex on thatpage in MSDN, and see that the value is treated as a verbatim string literal.

So, to only allow SSNs with hyphens, you just need to use:

```
ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}"
```

It is also ECMAScript-compliant and safe to use both at server and client, but you could further limit to

```
ValidationExpression="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"
```

Remember, `\d` at server-side can also match some non-standard (Arabic, etc) digits.